# Forcing imported method to use local variables

Tags: python, import, module, scope

I have a module 'b' importing a method from module "a", where method "a.method" uses a variable defined in "a" must be overriden in "b". simply, in codes:

```
module a.py:

local_var = 1
def method():
    print local_var

module b.py:

from a import method
local_var = 2
print method()
```

running python b.py prints 1, instead of 2. In my scenario imported method is a django
method so i can't modify the module, nor i want to copy the method to my module and modify it.

How can i override a local variable of another module and mkae the imported method use new variable?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I was trying to add jinja2 templates support to django without much hassle, though ended up with copying some django codes to override local variables. Final work is at github.com/altunyurt/djtemps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you better don't use such an approach. Pass the variable as the function argument, or use a class to encapsulate the value inside it.

If you insist:

Try the built-in [`exec`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) function:

> In all cases, if the optional parts are omitted, the code is executed in the current scope. If only the first expression after in is specified, it should be a dictionary, which will be used for both the global and the local variables. If two expressions are given, they are used for the global and local variables, respectively. If provided, locals can be any mapping object.

A working code:

a.py:

```
local_var = 1
def method():
    print local_var
```

b.py:

```
from a import method
import inspect

code = inspect.getsource(method)
local_var = 2
method()
print code
exec code
method()
```

`python b.py`:

```
vic@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ python b.py
1
def method():
    print local_var

2
vic@ubuntu:~/Desktop$
```

Comment: thank you, though i've used "exec expr in globals()" a few times, didn't really know what it ment up to now :)

Comment: "Pass the variable as the function argument, or use classes." - this had been helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. This is by design. Each module has its own namespace.

You can, however, save the current value of var, assign a new value, call the method and restore the original value.

```
# module a.py:

local_var = 1
def method():
    print local_var

# module b.py:

import a
old_local_var = a.local_var
a.local_var = 2
print method()
a.local_var = old_local_var
```

---

As jyore pointed out in the comment - this method should be used with care. It is more-or-less a hack. The only valid uses for this I can think of are testing or last resort measure, when everything else (including Chuck Norris) has failed.

Comment: you are correct, but the OP needs to be careful with this method, especially if he is using it on a server with multiple connections (he did mention django).  If multiple threads are writing to the same, now globalized variable, there could be unpredictable results from data writes.  I strongly suggest not using this pattern in this situation.